# Ktlint Custom Reporter

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, checkstyle

I'm working on improving my team's codestyle and ktlint seems like a perfect solution for the Kotlin we're introducing.

My problem is finding a full example for creating a customer reporter to allow for a custom output when running the ktlint gradle task.  Ktlint's docs say:

> In short, all you need to do is to implement a Reporter and make it available by registering a custom ReporterProvider using META-INF/services/com.github.shyiko.ktlint.core.ReporterProvider. Pack all of that into a JAR and you're done.

but following a simple example [here](https://medium.com/@takusemba/make-your-code-clean-with-ktlint-bf651c5924e8) but I have no idea where to place these files or where to place this "jar" that ktlint recommends or it says my custom reporter has not been found.

Does anyone have an example on how this works? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [mcassiano/ktlint-html-reporter](https://github.com/mcassiano/ktlint-html-reporter) or [one of the ktlint's built-in reporters](https://github.com/shyiko/ktlint/tree/master/ktlint-reporter-json).

In short, each reporter contains a Reporter, ReporterProvider, and a service definition (which contains ReporterProvider implementation classname):

```
$ cat src/main/kotlin/your/pkg/CustomReporter.kt
package your.pkg
import com.github.shyiko.ktlint.core.Reporter
class CustomReporter : Reporter {
...    

$ cat src/main/kotlin/your/pkg/CustomReporterProvider.kt
package your.pkg
import com.github.shyiko.ktlint.core.ReporterProvider
class CustomReporterProvider : CustomReporter {
...

$ cat src/main/resources/META-INF/services/com.github.shyiko.ktlint.core.ReporterProvider
your.pkg.CustomReporterProvider
```

You'll need to package that into a JAR.
Once you have a JAR, ktlint can load it in one of the following ways:

- `ktlint --reporter=custom,artifact=your.pkg:custom-reporter:0.1.0,output=target/output.html` (assuming `your.pkg:custom-reporter:0.1.0` is available in Maven Central / JCenter / JitPack)
- `ktlint --reporter=custom,artifact=~/path/to/custom-reporter.jar` (from fs)
- from a classpath (if you plan on using ktlint through [Gradle](https://github.com/shyiko/ktlint#-with-gradle)/[Maven](https://github.com/shyiko/ktlint#-with-maven)/etc), e.g.

  ```
  dependencies {
      ktlint "com.github.shyiko:ktlint:$ktlintVersion"
      ktlint "your.pkg:custom-reporter:0.1.0"
  }

  task ktlint(type: JavaExec, group: "verification") {
      classpath = configurations.ktlint
      main = "com.github.shyiko.ktlint.Main"
      args "--reporter=custom", "src/**/*.kt"
  }
  ```